# No effect on setViewController:animiated:?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

Basically I have

```
ViewControllerA *aVC = [[ViewControllerA alloc] init];

ViewControllerB *bVC = [[ViewControllerB alloc] init];

UITabBarController *tabBarVC = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

[tabBarVC setViewControllers:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:aVC, bVC, nil] animated:YES];
```

Now I can see the two tabs on the tabBarController but when I switch from one tab to another, I can't see any effects, neither on simulator or on real device. From the documentation I should be able to see fading right? Did I miss anything?

Comment: There shouldn't be any fading. Switching from one tab to the other has no animation by default.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass YES to `setViewControllers:animated:`, UITabBarController will animate the insertion of the the new tab bar items in the tab bar. It doesn't animate the transition between view controllers if the user then switches from one tab to another.